# TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given in my code

Tags: python

This:

```
import random

def main():

        userNumber1 = input("Choose a number from 1-20")
        userNumber2 = input("Choose another number from 1-20")
    if (userNumber1 == userNumber2):
        print("Invalid input")
    else:
        num1 = random.Random(userNumber1,userNumber2)
        num2 = random.Random(userNumber1,userNumber2)
        num3 = random.Random(userNumber1,userNumber2)
    while (num1==num2 or num1==num3 or num3==num2):
        if (num3==num2):
            del num2
            num2 = random.Random(userNumber1,userNumber2)
        elif (num1==num3):
            del num3
            num3 = random.Random(userNumber1,userNumber2)
        elif (num1==num2):
            del num2
            num2 = random.Random(userNumber1,userNumber2)
        else:
            pass
    print(str(num1)+str(num2)+str(num3))
main()
```

is giving back the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Does anyone know why and help me troubleshoot?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: The is no `__init__()` in the code you have posted. Please also fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Yes, the full error traceback please. We need to know which line is causing the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to choose one of the two numbers at random, or a number between the two numbers. Either way, `Random` takes a *seed* as an argument; you want to use one of the methods of `Random` to actually generate a random number.

Comment: Also user input has to be converted to int

Comment: Minor suggestion: `print(str(num1)+str(num2)+str(num3))` => `print(f"{num1}{num2}{num3}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`random.Random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.Random) is a class. You construct an instance of it if you want your own random number generator based on a given seed or a given algorithm.

It looks like you're simply trying to construct some random integers in a range, so you're looking for [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint).

> `random.randint(a, b)`
>
> Return a random integer `N` such that `a <= N <= b`. Alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`.

Note that the bounds are inclusive, so `a` and `b` are valid returns from this function. Adjust your bounds as needed if that's not intentional.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to generate random numbers between the user input bounds, the function you're looking for is [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint):

```py
r = random.randint(3, 12)    # -> returns a random integer 3 <= r < 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.randint()` instead of `random.Random()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all indent user Inputs 1 tab backwards,from the look of it you are trying to get a random no between user inputs for this purpose use `Random.randint` here is the error free code .

```
import random

def main():

    userNumber1 = int(input("Choose a number from 1-20"))
    userNumber2 = int(input("Choose another number from 1-20"))
    if userNumber1 == userNumber2:
        print("Invalid input")
    else:
        num1 = random.randint(userNumber1,userNumber2)
        num2 = random.randint(userNumber1,userNumber2)
        num3 = random.randint(userNumber1,userNumber2)
    while (num1==num2 or num1==num3 or num3==num2):
        if (num3==num2):
            del num2
            num2 = random.randint(userNumber1,userNumber2)
        elif (num1==num3):
            del num3
            num3 = random.randint(userNumber1,userNumber2)
        elif (num1==num2):
            del num2
            num2 = random.randint(userNumber1,userNumber2)
        else:
            pass
    print(str(num1)+str(num2)+str(num3))
main()
```